# Database backend for git repository

Tags: git, tfs

When you are creating projects under one collection on TFS 2013 there is still one database for each team project collection (name should be Tfs_Collection). For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400720.aspx.

Has it changed by supporting GIT as second version control? What if I have one collection with projects based on both vc's - GIT and TFVC? Still one Tfs_Collection database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is unchanged, there is still one "Collection Database" per Team Project Collection that can contain multiple team projects, each using their own Version Control choices. I have some git stuff in my Collection database - even though I am on 2012 Update 3 still, using only TFVC.